# Can't connect to web server over FTP in PhpStorm on a Mac

Tags: macos, ftp, phpstorm

I often use PhpStorm feature of connecting to web server over FTP on my work computer on Windows and it works just fine.

Today I tried to do it on my Mac, it alerted that connection was successful but for some reason it does't list any of the files on my website.

I also tried another website and got the same result - connection was successful but none of the files were available.

Here are some screenshots of the steps I made:

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bkvc.jpg)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVzCh.jpg)

Step 3 (in comments)

I must say that further creating of the project and viewing 'Browse Remote Host' doesn't show files either.

Comment: Step 3 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/jKsCU.jpg

Comment: Try switching between Active & Passive FTP modes (use another one to what you having right now) -- almost always helps.

Comment: Thanks, files are visible now. But downloading is going very slowly. Is passive mode slower than active?

Comment: AFAIK -- no. The difference is in the way how FTP client communicates with FTP server (how they negotiate about what ports to use). Do you have any 3rd party FTP client (e.g. FileZilla)? See if it will be working any faster. You may download your site locally using 3rd party client and then just use "Open " and point to that local folder -- IDE will create project using those files.

Comment: Will I be able to deploy changes back to server if I use this method?

Comment: Sure -- you will just need to configure your Deployment manually as project created this way is configured with defaults only. Basically, New Project Wizard just simplifies few things and covers the most often used and rather simple scenario and whatever it does can be configured manually at any time.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your responds!